# The function clearInterval() is not working React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to stop the setInterval function that generates a random number every 100ms after we click but my clearInterval won't do anything.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
    const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState ('CLICK');
    const generateRandomNumber = () => {
        setInterval(() => {setRandomNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 )}, 100);
    };
    const stopWheel = () => {
        clearInterval(generateRandomNumber);
        console.log(randomNumber);
    };
    const spinWheel = () => {
        generateRandomNumber();
        setTimeout(stopWheel, 2000);
    };
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={spinWheel}>
          <Text>{randomNumber}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you're trying to clear a function instead of an interval. Try something like this instead:

```
let timer;
  const generateRandomNumber = () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => { setRandomNumber(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1) }, 100);
  };
  const stopWheel = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log(randomNumber);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it!